# Magento 2.3 inline Edit ui component grid what's the use of "all in column" field?

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.3.1

I'm developing an admin grid for my custom module with the inlineEdit active instead of the usual edit link in action column.

The grid works fine and also the inlineEdit works as intended.

My only question is about the ***"all in column"*** field that appears when I'm in edit line mode.

I cannot understand what this field is for. If I write something in this field, the ***"save edits"*** button become disabled so I cannot save anything.

So what's this field for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All in column** field is useful when you want to apply same value to the multiple columns.

So, rather than copy pasting same value by clicking on each columns, you can just select records and under your desired column, in All in column you can put your values and click **Apply** and than **Save**.

Here's an example to perfectly describe how it works:

> Suppose I want to change same value to this column as shown in below
>   image:

[image]

> So you can write that value in all in column as

[image]

> And you'll have following output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**All in column** is used to set entered values in all the selected rows.

[image]

In this example (CMS/Page), I'm editing 4 rows simultaneously.

Let's say, if I want to update **Title** for all selected rows to "**Test Title**", then I just need to set "**Test Title**" in "**All in Column**" input field and click Apply button.

This will set **Title** for all selected rows to "**Test Title**".

If you have entered/selected any value for "**All in Column**" input/select fields, **SAVE** button will be disabled until you apply the changes by pressing **Apply** button.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I understood what was wrong in my grid: I had no action column (no need since the edit was inline) so I had no apply button. Adding the action column made the apply button visible so now I can see that the value of the field gets saved for all the selected items.

Thanks